# Transform directory structure

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, scripting, directory-structure

I have the following folder structure

```
root folder
 |-al2
   |- GER.zip
   |- ENG.zip
 |-ww
   |- GER.zip
   |- ENG.zip
```

and so on. The folder names are random strings.

I want to sort the files in the following way:

```
root folder
 |-ENG
   |-al2
     |- ENG.zip
   |-ww
     |- ENG.zip
 |-GER
   |-al2
     |- GER.zip
   |-ww
     |- GER.zip
```

How can I automate this?

**UPDATE**: The folder names do not follow any kind of system. They are random strings.

Comment: Do you mean you want to alter the directory structure or simply display it differently?  Your question is a bit ambiguous on that point.

Comment: I want to alter the structure. I'm sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./*/* ; do
    lang=${file%.zip}            # Remove the extension.
    lang=${lang#./*/}            # Remove the folder.
    mkdir -p "$lang/${file%/*}"  # Create the target folders.
    mv "$file" "$lang/$file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, almost perfect. But I've meant the Folder1, Folder2 only as an example. Actually I have folder names that don't follow any kind of system. al2, ww, zen, some have numbers, some are 2 characters long, some are 3 characters long.

Comment: @pdg I've updated the answer for you - try now.  I've also added some missing quotes.  This method of iterating over globs with a for loop and using proper quoting is much safer than the piping `find` output approach.  You should prefer this one as long as it works.